# Apache Commons CLI: prevent repeated options & force exactly one argument?

Tags: apache-commons-cli

I am using **commons-cli 1.5.0**. Let's say my command line syntax is the following:

```
Process -src <input> -dst <output>
```

My program ("Process") should accept exactly one **-src** and exactly one **-dst**.
However, **DefaultParser** allows such command lines as:

```
Process -src aaa.txt -src bbb.txt -src ccc.txt -dst result.txt
```

For the above line, **getOptionValue("src")** returns **"aaa.txt"**, but **getOptionValues("src")** returns all 3 filenames.

Now, is there an option to disallow such syntax? To define that there can only be one **-src**, and if there are more, **DefaultParser.parse()** should throw an exception?
I've tried **.hasArgs().numberOfArgs(1)** and **.hasArg().numberOfArgs(1)**,
but it did not seem to change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to do this check yourself and fail the app yourself after parsing, e.g.

```
CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
if (cmd.getOptionValues("src").length > 1) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot handle more than one 'src' argument");
}
```